# ingress-nginx connects from outside minikube, but connection is refused from inside minikube

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I am trying to access my ingress-nginx service from a service but it gives connection refused. Here is my ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: auth-srv
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/tickets/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: tickets-srv
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client-srv
              servicePort: 3000
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: http
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
```

```
❯ kubectl get services -n ingress-nginx
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx   LoadBalancer   10.101.124.218   10.101.124.218   80:30634/TCP,443:30179/TCP   15m
```

The ingress-nginx is running on namespace ingress-nginx.
So it should be accessible by `http://ingress-nginx.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local`. But when I access it, it says `connection refused 10.101.124.218:80`. I am able to access the ingress from outside, i.e. from the `ingress` ip.

I am using minikube and used ingress by running `minikube addons enable ingress`. Yes and im running the tunnel by `minikube tunnel`

Comment: can you write the exact command you execute to access the service?

Comment: kubectl apply -f ingress-svc.yaml

Comment: I mean, for example, the curl command you run against the endpoint. You do `curl http://ingress-nginx.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local`?How do you try to access the service?

Comment: Yes I ran `wget http://ingress-nginx.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local` inside the pod running a service. `kubectl exec -it <pod_name> sh` and still got connection refused

Comment: when you do that the host is `cluster.local`, you need to pass a header that spacifies ticketing.dev. Try `curl -H "Host: ticketing.dev" ingress-nginx.ingress-nginx`. That one should get to `client-srv` service.

Comment: Nope... Not working

Comment: The actual api request is made in a nextJS app. There i was passing the host, and still refused

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested your environment and found the same behavior, external access but internally getting connection refused, this is how I solved:

- The Minikube Ingress Addon deploys the controller in `kube-system` namespace. If you try to deploy the service in a newly created namespace, it will not reach the deployment in `kube-system` namespace.
- It's easy to mix those concepts because the default `nginx-ingress` deployment uses the namespace `ingress-nginx` as you were trying.
- Another issue I found, is that your service does not have all selectors assigned to the controller deployment.
- The easiest way to make your deployment work, is to run `kubectl expose` on the nginx controller:

```
kubectl expose deployment ingress-nginx-controller --target-port=80 --type=NodePort -n kube-system
```

- Using this command to create the nginx-ingress-controller service, all communications were working, both external and internal.

---

**Reproduction:**

- For this example I'm using only two ingress backends to avoid being much repetitive in my explanation.
- Using minikube 1.11.0
- Enabled `ingress` and `metallb` addons.
- Deployed two hello apps: `v1` and `v2`, both pods listens on port `8080` and are exposed as node port as follows:

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
hello1-svc   NodePort    10.110.211.119   <none>        8080:31243/TCP   95m
hello2-svc   NodePort    10.96.9.66       <none>        8080:31316/TCP   93m
```

- Here is the ingress file, just like yours, just changed the backend services names and ports to match my deployed ones:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: hello1-svc
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: hello2-svc
              servicePort: 8080
```

- Now I'll create the `nginx-ingress` service exposing the controller deployment, this way all tags and settings will be inherited:

```
$ kubectl expose deployment ingress-nginx-controller --target-port=80 --type=NodeP
ort -n kube-system
service/ingress-nginx-controller exposed
```

- Now we deploy the ingress object:

```
$ kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml 
ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress-service created

$ kubectl get ingress
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS           ADDRESS      PORTS   AGE
ingress-service   <none>   ticketing.dev   172.17.0.4   80      56s

$ minikube ip
172.17.0.4
```

- Testing the ingress from the outside:

```
$ tail -n 1 /etc/hosts
172.17.0.4 ticketing.dev

$ curl http://ticketing.dev/?foo
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: hello2-67bbbf98bb-s78c4

$ curl http://ticketing.dev/api/users/?foo
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: hello-576585fb5f-67ph5
```

- Then I deployed a `alpine` pod to test the access from inside the cluster:

```
$ kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 -it alpine --image=alpine -- /bin/sh
/ # nslookup ingress-nginx-controller.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

Name:   ingress-nginx-controller.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.98.167.112

/ # apk update
/ # apk add curl

/ # curl -H "Host: ticketing.dev" ingress-nginx-controller.kube-system.svc.cluster.local/?foo
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: hello2-67bbbf98bb-s78c4

/ # curl -H "Host: ticketing.dev" ingress-nginx-controller.kube-system.svc.cluster.local/api/users/?foo
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: hello-576585fb5f-67ph5
```

As you can see, all requests were fulfilled.

---

**Note:**

- As pointed by **@suren**, when curling ingress, I had to specify the host with -H
- The service name needs to be fully FQDN because we are dealing with a service hosted in another namespace, using the format `<SVC_NAME>.<NAMESPACE>.svc.cluster.local`.
- In your JS app, you will have to pass the `Host` argument in order to reach the ingress.

If you have any question let me know in the comments.

Comment: Do I just run `kubectl expose deployment ingress-nginx-controller --target-port=80 --type=LoadBalancer -n kube-system`?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can even set the service as ClusterIP if you don't want it to be exposed externally.

Comment: @willrof, I do not understand what you did. I followed as much as I got and all I got was just confirmation that I keep getting 502 Bad Gateway, but not how to solve it. I have the same exact ingress-nginx yaml file as the OP, I can tail -n 1 /etc/hosts successfully but I cannot curl without getting the same 502 Gateway I get in Postman. What exactly is the problem? Why are my routes bad gateways when it is what I have in my express route handler?

Comment: @Daniel are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: @AmitParameshwar, I am not, but if you feel you have a good solution for this feel free to post.